# merge and replace values in two data.tables

Tags: r, data.table

I am quite new to the data.table package and have a simple problem. I have two data.tables that are compared with the use of keys. In data.table 1 the value of column C is changed from "NO" to "OK" if the key columns A and B are equally found in data.table B. This step is inevitably and has to be done.

```
library(data.table)
df_1 <- data.frame(A=c(1,1,3,5,6,7), B = c("x","y","z","q","w","e"), C = rep("NO",6))
df_2 <- data.frame(A=c(3,5,1), B = c("z","q","x"), D=c(3,5,99))
keys <- c("A","B")
dt_1 <- data.table(df_1, key = keys)
dt_2 <- data.table(df_2, key = keys)
dt_1[dt_2, C := "OK"]
```

Now I get the data.table:

```
   A     B     C
1: 1     x     OK
2: 1     y     NO
3: 3     z     OK
4: 5     q     OK
5: 6     w     NO
6: 7     e     NO
```

I would like to include a second operation. If in data.table 2 the value of column A is not equal to column D the value of column D should be used after the first operation. Meaning column D is superior to A. This should work no matter how many values in D are different. The desired data.table looks the following:

```
   A     B     C
1: 99    x     OK
2: 1     y     NO
3: 3     z     OK
4: 5     q     OK
5: 6     w     NO
6: 7     e     NO
```

I tired something without success.

```
dt_1[dt_2, A != D, A := D]
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

```
dt_1[C == "OK", A:= dt_2[,D]]

#   A B  C
# 1: 99 x OK
# 2:  1 y NO
# 3:  3 z OK
# 4:  5 q OK
# 5:  6 w NO
# 6:  7 e NO
```

---

And here's how you should have done the whole process in the first place.

Create both data sets as `data.table`s in the first place (or convert *in place* using `setDT`)

```
dt_1 <- data.table(A=c(1,1,3,5,6,7), B = c("x","y","z","q","w","e"), C = rep("NO",6))
dt_2 <- data.table(A=c(3,5,1), B = c("z","q","x"), D=c(3,5,99))
```

Then key them using `setkeyv` instead of using the `<-` operator

```
keys <- c("A","B")
setkeyv(dt_1, keys)
setkeyv(dt_2, keys)
```

Then just update both column within a single join

```
dt_1[dt_2, `:=`(C = "OK", A = i.D)]
#     A B  C
# 1: 99 x OK
# 2:  1 y NO
# 3:  3 z OK
# 4:  5 q OK
# 5:  6 w NO
# 6:  7 e NO
```

In this case the condition `df_1$A != df_2$D` is redundant

Comment: As I understand if you change some velue in `dt_2$D` so the corresponding value in `dt_1$A` should be changed... anyway you are right, it's just a quick solution to his question. I am looking for some more general avoiding a step of the column C in dt_1

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. The step to set column C to OK is inevitable. I edited the question.

Comment: @DavidArenburg, after `dt_2[2L, D := 1e3]` value A is different D in row 2, so in dt_1[3,A] is changed to 1000

Comment: @Andriy T. so far it seems to work for me the way it is supposed to work. I will take a closer look in my actual code.

Comment: Yeah, my mistake. I overthinking it. I guess it also works.

Comment: I guess this should be just a one liner for both operation at once ```dt_1[dt_2, `:=`(C = "OK", A = D)]```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I will take a closer look to the data.table syntax to become more comfortable with it.

Comment: @DavidArenburg, thank's for your edit! I forgot how good is `data.table` while doing a few operations in a single line